# Add new Row to DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I have a `DataGrid` bind to a database with one Table and one Column (FooTable and FooName).
With my following code, I can bind `DataGrid` to `DataTable` and display database data. But when each time I add a new row by `DataSet_Add_Click()`, nothing gets added to the `DataGrid`. I though I have bind `DataTable` to `DataGrid` through `ItemsSource`, but adding new row to DataTable doesn't add row to DataGrid. Why?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection();

    /* Define the Connection String */
    string connString;
    DataGrid dg1 = new DataGrid();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        connString = @"...";

        SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();

        SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter();

        string sqlStr = @"SELECT * FROM FooTable";
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCeCommand(sqlStr, conn);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "FooTable");

        dt = ds.Tables["FooTable"];

        dg1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables;

        DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
        newRow["FooName"] = "Mary";
        dt.Rows.Add(newRow);

        CreateDataGrid();
    }

    public struct DataItem1
    {
        public string FooName { get; set; }
    }

    private void CreateDataGrid()
    {
        DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn();

        col = new DataGridTextColumn();
        col.Binding = new Binding("FooName");
        col.Header = "FooName";
        dg1.Columns.Add(col);

        /* dataGrid1 exist in XAML and is a parent of the DataGrid */
        dataGrid1.Children.Add(dg1);
    }

    private void DataSet_Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow newRow2 = dt.NewRow();
        newRow2["FooName"] = "Mary";
        dt.Rows.Add(newRow2);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `SqlCeConnection conn` doing in your `DataSet_Add_Click` method, and why `SqlCeException` being caught?

Comment: Are you adding the dataTable back to the ItemsSource after you have added the new rows?

Comment: Perhaps try binding your DataTable directly as the ItemsSource instead of the DataSet. The way you have it is the correct way to add rows to a DataTable. The issue seems to do something with the datasource binding.

Comment: I believe you should subscribe for the **dt.TableNewRow** and assign the source again;

Comment: Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5813313/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pls post your xaml or cs code where you bind the Itemssource.

does your DataSet_Add_Click add the row to your datatable? if yes then it seems is just a refresh/binding problem with your datagrid.

when i work with datatables and datagrid i always use the following

```
//ctor or init
dt = ds.Tables["FooTable"];
//the next line you have to write after you initialize your datatable
this.MyView = (BindingListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.dt);
```

XAML

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyView }"/>
```

Refresh

```
this.MyView.Refresh();
```

EDIT:
MyView is a property

```
public BindingListCollectionView MyView
{ 
   get {return this._myview;}
   set {this._myview = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyView");
}
```

you can do binding in code.

```
 Binding myBinding = new Binding("MyView");
 myBinding.Source = this;//the instance with the MyView property
 mydatagridctrl.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
```

Comment: @blindmeis, thanks. But my DataGrid is generated in code (run-time) So I cannot use XAML. How can I do the binding on DataGrid in code behind? If possible, Can you edit your answer?

Comment: @blinddmeis, btw what is MyView? I cannot find Refresh() method in a control like DataGrid...

Comment: setting the itemssource in code behind without binding should also work. this.mydatagridctrl.ItemsSource=this.MyView

Comment: refresh is called on the BindingListCollectionView: this.MyView.Refresh()

Comment: @blindmeis - thanks for your effort. But it seems people keep misunderstanding what the problem is. The answer is on the other thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815014/how-to-bind-a-datagrid-to-a-datatable-all-in-code-behind 

The solution is: 
datagrid.ItemsSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;

Comment: thx. i dont use setting itemssource in codebehind so much. my solution to set datagrid.ItemsSource = this.MyView is pretty much the same but the more wpf way. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hi i edit my answer in your [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813313/add-new-row-to-datatable/5814579#5814579) .

the general way i use when working with datatables, datagrid and wpf/mvvm:

i always bind the datagrid itemssource to the BindingListCollectionView of the datatable.
i do this because i can easily filter, refresh or add/delete/modify the datatable items.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the end of your `DataSet_Add_Click` method

```
dg1.Items.Refresh();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try calling `dt.DataBind();` at the end.

Comment: there is no such method. I've already did the binding in the first line: dg1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables;

Comment: I missed the WPF tag - try `dg1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0];`

Comment: or dg1.ItemsSource = dt; being that the DataTable is accessible within your current method.

Comment: actually it should be:

dg1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;